# How can I add a custom mobile device to google chrome emulator with correct screen sizes?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, emulation, screen-resolution

I need to add the **Moto 4G Plus** to the Chrome emulator. 
I can't figure out what sizes should I type in. The screen is 5.5" and resolution 1080x1920 with 401 PPI.

What I can add in the Chrome emulator is *Width*, *Height*, and *Pixel Ratio*.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068203/how-to-test-site-in-motorola-g-in-chrome-emulator) there is a similar question, as far as I understood, I should divide the resolution by 2 or 3 and then setting the *Pixel Ratio* to 2 or 3 depending which one I used to divide. But I'm not sure at all about this.

If everything is correct I should have a correct emulation of the Moto G4 Plus with:

`WxH: 360x640 PR: 3`